# How to find indication of a Validation error (required="true") while doing ajax command

Tags: jsf-2

I have a form inside a dialog which I close by clicking on commandbutton with ajax ,

like this

```
<h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{myBean.addSomething(false)}"
    id="add_something_id" >
    <f:ajax render="@form someTable" execute="@form"
        onevent="closeAddNewSomethingDialogIfSucceeded"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

and here is the js code for closing the dialog

```
    function closeAddNewSomethingDialogIfSucceeded(data) {
        if(data.status === 'success') {
            $("#dialog_id").dialog("close");
        }
    }
```

No problems till here...

Now I changed some of the dialog form fields into `required="true"` and now I want to prevent the closing of the dialog of i got validation errors...

But the ajax `data.status` still reaches its `success` state , and I can't figure out what indication of validation failure I can hook on...

any ideas?

**Thanks to BalusC answer I did the following:**

in JSF , added :

```
    <h:panelGroup id="global_flag_validation_failed_render">
        <h:outputText id="global_flag_validation_failed" value="true" 
            rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

the f:ajax was changed into

```
<f:ajax render="@form someTable global_flag_validation_failed_render"
```

and in js added the following check

```
if(data.status === 'success') {
    if($("#global_flag_validation_failed").length === 0){
         $("#dialog_id").dialog("close");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Not specifically for `required="true"`, but you can check by [`#{facesContext.validationFailed}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) if validation has failed in general. If you combine this with  checking if the button in question is pressed by [`#{not empty param[buttonClientId]}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29), then you can put it together in the `rendered` attribute of the [`<h:outputScript>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) as follows:

```
<h:commandButton id="add_something_id" binding="#{add}" value="Add" action="#{myBean.addSomething(false)}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form someTable" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty param[add.clientId] and not facesContext.validationFailed}">
    $("#dialog_id").dialog("close");
</h:outputScript>
```

*(note that you need to make sure that the script is also re-rendered by f:ajax)*

A bit hacky, but it's not possible to handle it in the `onevent` function as the standard JSF implementation doesn't provide any information about the validation status in the ajax response.

If you happen to use RichFaces, then you could just use EL in the `oncomplete` attribute of the `<a4j:xxx>` command button/link. They are namely evaluated on a per-request basis instead of on a per-view basis as in standard JSF and PrimeFaces:

```
<a4j:commandButton ... oncomplete="if (#{!facesContext.validationFailed}) $('#dialog_id').dialog('close')" />
```

Or if you happen to use PrimeFaces, then you could take advantage of the fact that PrimeFaces extends the ajax response with an additional `args.validationFailed` attribute which is injected straight in the JavaScript scope of the `oncomplete` attribute:

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) $('#dialog_id').dialog('close')" />
```

*(note that `&amp;` is been used instead of `&`, because `&` is a special character in XML/XHTML)*

Or you could use the PrimeFaces' `RequestContext` API in the bean's action method to programmatically execute JavaScript in the rendered view.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#dialog_id').dialog('close')");
```

No conditional checks are necessary as the bean's action method won't be invoked anyway when the validation has failed.

Comment: Thank! eventually I used relied on the #{facesContext.validationFailed} (I wasn't aware of it) I used it in a render condition of simple outputext... and later on In the js code i checked for that outputtext existence using the jquery .length ...

Comment: You're welcome. For an overview of implicit EL objects in JSF, see also [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects).

Comment: @BalusC Does facesContext.validationFailed applies for conversion failures too ? Is it true if conversion is failed ?

Comment: @Bren Yes. According to the Java EE 6 FacesContext documentation, "validationFailed() Sets a flag which indicates that a conversion or validation error occurred while processing the inputs." (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#validationFailed())

Comment: Note that you don't have to use &amp;&amp;... You can instead use "and"...

Comment: @Andrew You're confusing JS with EL.

Comment: @BalusC You are correct. I must have used EL in a different attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at PrimeFaces' [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml). This would help you trigger client-side code on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Two things
1) Checking for an error in the 'onevent' function

Surely you have a message tag for the mandatory field?

```
<h:message id="m-my-field-id" for="my-field-id" errorClass="error-class"/>
```

So you can check for the error-class something like

```
var message = $('#m-my-field-id');

if(message.hasClass('error-class'){
    //do this
}
else{
  //do that
}
```

2) The DOM isn't up to date on success

Yes, I can see the message on the page in Firefox, yet jQuery tells me it is not there.

I have found that using the smallest possible timeout is sufficient to fix this

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
    setErrorStyle(source.attr('id'));
    },
   1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@BalusC

in your example code the clientId of the button is not set as a param because it is a AJAX request. So

```
not empty param[add.clientId] is always false.
```

But this works:

```
param['javax.faces.source'] eq add.clientId
```

(tested with jsf-impl-2.2.12.redhat-1)

regards