# Navigation to new tab hangs when 2 javascript commands in onclick

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Using PF 10, JSF 2.3

I try to open a url in a new tab when the user clicks on "Download report"

xhtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function start() {
        PF('statusDialog').show();
    }

    function stop() {
        PF('statusDialog').hide();
    }
    //]]>
   </script>

<h:form>
    <p:menubar>
        <p:menuitem value="Home" action="#{umigonBean.logout}" icon="pi pi-home"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Download report" action="#{umigonBean.getReport}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start);" icon="pi pi-arrow-down" oncomplete="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(stop);"/>
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean (session scoped, if this matters):

```
    public void getReport(){
       // report being generated in the form of a Google Slide...
       // when it is generated, a redirect is made to the url of this Google Slide:

       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       context.getExternalContext().redirect("http://docs.google.com/etc");
    }
```

The solutions suggested by @BalusC [for a commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611296/open-new-window-by-post-using-hcommandbutton) are:

- **`<h:form target="_blank">`**
  (does not apply as my form contains different links, and only this one should open a new tab)
- **`onclick="this.form.target='_blank'"`**

In my code above this would be:

```
onclick="this.form.target='_blank';PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start);"
```

however when I choose this option, the action is not called (the "waiting" window appears and remains for ever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by the point 3 of the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14585524/798502):

```
public void submit() { 
     // ...
     PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("window.open('myUrl');");
 }
```